# Data on one portable hard drive show different permissions (700 and 777) in two computers

Tags: permissions, filesystem, backup

#### Situation

I have removed Ubuntu 14.04 from my laptop and installed 16.04.6. Before installing I made a copy of the `/opt` directory on a portable hard drive using `rsync`. After installing I wanted to copy that backup copy into the newly created `/opt`. (I am aware now that I could have saved the original \opt from reformatting while installing, but it went this way and sounds still not unreasonable.)

I am experiencing strange outcomes with rsync-ing the portable hard-drive content and the new /opt. It causes systematic freezes and this is discussed on the other post [Systematic freeze of fresh Ubuntu 16.04.6 when running rsync](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166597/systematic-freeze-of-fresh-ubuntu-16-04-6-when-running-rsync). Actually I also noticed that I get a freeze when I launch a `tree -d -L 2` on the portable hard drive.

#### Research

While investigating the issue, I have found out the following:

- If I look into the portable hard drive from a computer with Ubuntu 14.04, all directories have permission **700** (expected)
- If I look into it from the laptop with the new Ubuntu 16.04, all directories have permission **777** (unexpected)

Note that the user and group names of the directories exist in both computer and laptop. I also think this concerns all files contained in each directory, although I didn't look into it systematically.

**Added**   The file system of the portable drive is nfts.
The drive is mounted automatically by plugging it into the usb port.

#### Question

This was most puzzling to me. Is it possible that the same data get different permissions when seen by different computers? 
If not, how can this come about and how to fix it? 
If yes, I consider this kind of scary: is there a way to guarantee consistency?

Comment: What is the filesystem on the portable drive, and how are you mounting it in the two cases?

Comment: `mount` will list your mounts, also `/opt` and `\opt` are very  different. Which do you mean?

Comment: @steeldriver Information added in the body of the post

Comment: @waltinator Typos corrected